# Execute sh script during build

Tags: maven, plugins

I have this plugin in pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <executions>
                <execution><!-- Run our version calculation script -->
                    <id>Version Calculation</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>${basedir}/target/process.properties</workingDirectory>
                        <executable>${basedir}/Scripts.sh</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Process.Properties file

```
link.item=true
link.process=false
link.process.run=Downloads_Item.txt$
```

Scripts.sh

```
   #!/bin/bash
   sed 's/Downloads_Item/Downloads_Item_NiteVate/g' Process.properties
```

I am trying to replace the value of the flag `link.process.run` by executing `Scripts.sh`.

I tried but its not worked. This should happen while taking build.
I am not able to find where is the problem

Comment: `<workingDirectory>` should reference an existing directory, I think you referenced a file. Does maven produce an error or what is the output?

Comment: you don't need a script to replace a value in a file during the build, maven can do that for you out-of-the-box via [filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Comment: [filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) is not possible becuase Process.properties is a properties file. I cannot add a variable there. Baiscally I have to replace a value while taking build.

Comment: I didnt get any error, build success. but changes didnt happened.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Listen to @A.DiMatteo. The Maven way is to filter your properties. Why can't you do that? You can filter `.properties` file.

Comment: you mean I have to create one more properties files for changing one flag in the properties file